# How to extractimage at a specified position using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am able to use htmlagilitypack to extract first image from a website. But I want to be able to extract blog post feature image. I am using firstOrDefault and it gives me the first image on the given url.

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stack Overflow, Can you please some of your code?

Comment: Show us something that you have already tried. StackOverflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: Dim url As String = "http://mashable.com/2016/05/27/cellphone-cancer-study/"
'Dim web = New HtmlWeb()
'Dim document = web.Load(url)

Dim imgg = document.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(Function(n) n.Name = "img").FirstOrDefault()
image.ImageUrl = imgg.GetAttributeValue("src", String.Empty)

this only give me the first image on the blog instead of the feature image of the blog post and when i do something like:
Dim imgg = document.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(Function(n) n.Name = "img").elementAt(1)
image.ImageUrl = imgg.GetAttributeValue("src", String.Empty)
I get error